# Cleaner formatting for advanced search operators terms

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search

I just ran a search using one of the advanced operators for the first time.

Search:

```
[tag] wiki:1
```

Result:

```
posts containing

wiki:1

within these tags
[tag]
```

I really dislike the phrase "posts containing 'wiki:1'" since I specifically wasn't searching for that term. Perhaps the advanced operators need to be changed so that the output on the resulting page is a bit cleaner.

e.g.:

```
community-wiki posts containing

within these tags
[tag]
```

Comment: @Jeff: One mans bug is another mans feature (and vice versa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We made some tweaks to the search UI recently as part of the Lucene change.  Advances search options are now split out, e.g. [`posts containing  wiki:1`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=posts+containing++wiki:1) will now result in:

```
posts containing
terms here

search options
wiki:1
```